# Python3 - using for loop in a if condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to do things like this with a for in a single line, can i do it or i have to use a filter?

```
not 0 <= n <= 255 for n in [-1, 256, 23]
# True
0 <= n <= 255 for n in [0, 255, 256]
# False
0 <= n <= 255 for n in [0, 24, 255]
# True
```

Comment: You can use `all(..)` and `any(..)` for this. Here you want `all`, so `if all(0 <= n <= 255 for n in [-1,256,23]):`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#all):

```
all(0 <= n <= 255 for n in [0, 255, 256])
# False
all(0 <= n <= 255 for n in [0, 24, 255])
# True
not all(0 <= n <= 255 for n in [-1, 256, 23])
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

I like doing such all-in-range checks like this:

```
0 <= min(nums) <= max(nums) <= 255
```

That's usually faster.

Measuring a little:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('0 <= min(nums) <= max(nums) <= 255', 'nums = range(256)')
10.911965313750706
>>> timeit('all(0 <= n <= 255 for n in nums)', 'nums = range(256)')
23.402136341237693
```

Comment: Interesting, given that both `min` and `max` have to iterate the collection. Algorithmically `0 <= min(nums) and max(nums) <= 255` should be better..

Comment: @schwobaseggl Well, the iterations are simpler (only one comparison for each value), there's no generator overhead, and no Python code runs for each value. I just measured `all([0 <= n for n in nums])` and that took 12.7 seconds.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Here I did, yes. Python 3.6.1. Why?

Comment: About your "`and` should be better" and also about `all` having the advantage of being able to stop early: The reason I do this stuff is to catch mistakes in data for coding contests, to ensure that all test data is valid. Which means that I fully expect all values to be in the range and thus fully expect having to run all tests. And I suspect that's quite usual, not just for me and my use cases.

Comment: Interesting again, the timings don't care whether `range(x)` or `list(range(x))` is used...

Comment: Yup, of course. For data where most is outside the range, `all` is much faster

Comment: @schwobaseggl Ha, well, if it *were* constant time, then it wouldn't be only twice as fast :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162131/discussion-between-schwobaseggl-and-stefan-pochmann).

Answer (score 0):

```
func = lambda n: 0 <= n <= 255

print(not all(map(func, [-1, 256, 23])))
# True
print(all(map(func, [0, 255, 256])))
# False
print(all(map(func, [0, 24, 255])))
# True
```